# Deleting specific object based on id but its delete all all the objects from json

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am creating a simple employees crud app in which i can delete individual employees. but when ever i am deleting any employee its deleting all the employees in db.json and makes its empty.

**Basically DELETE call deletes all the entries**

**component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i = index">
      <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
      <td>{{employee.employeeId}}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.address }}</td>
        <button type="button" style="margin-left:10px" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEmployee(employee.id)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
```

**component.ts**

```
deleteEmployee(employeeId:number){
    this.employeesDataService.deleteEmployee(employeeId).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data",  data);//Getting blank object in risponse
      let newEmployees = this.employees.filter(data => data.id !== employeeId);
      this.employees = newEmployees;
      console.log(this.employees);
    })
  }
```

**service**

```
deleteEmployee(id:number){
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`) 
  }
```

**db.json**

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "employeeId": "HCL1",
      "name": "Mark",
      "age": 24,
      "email": "mark@gmail.com",
      "mobile": "455463242",
      "address": "abx, near abc, India"
      
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "employeeId": "HCL21",
      "name": "Jack",
      "age": 21,
      "email": "jack@gmail.com",
      "mobile": "455463242",
      "address": "xyz, near abc, India"
      
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in stackblitz?

Comment: `"address": "xyz, near abc, India"
      
    }
    }` your JSON is malformed?

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting employee based `employeeId` so change `data.id` to `data.employeeId`

```
  let newEmployees = this.employees.filter(data => data.employeeId !== employeeId);
```

Comment: not this is not the issue, here i am filtering out the undeleted object based on id. before this in .subscribe(data ....data has empty object.

Answer (score 0):

JSON-Server was looking at the database and removing entries that reference other entries that don't exist (based on the parentId property).

To fix it I removed the employoeeId and used only id in json file. Other option is to create db like below.

```
{
  "users": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ],
  "employees": {
    // ...
  }
}
```